# How to parse the command output by rows and store it array variable?

Tags: mfc, cmd

```
for /f %a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run') do @echo %a|find /v "\"
```

OUTPUT:
`XSENZ
Persistence
IntelliPoint
IgfxTray
HotKeysCmds`

I need to Parse it one by one and save it into CStringArray .Is it possible? please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the API.

[RegEnumValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do the Job.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution above truncates the names in some cases.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` to remove the leading and trailing spaces - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" ^|repl " *(.*?) *REG_.*?.*" "$1" ') do (
set /a c+=1
set n=000!c!
set n=!n:~-2!
set "var[!n!]=%%a"
)
set var[
pause
```